# import props, destructuring assignment & unresolved variable warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm a bit new at frontend, so I have a question about code practices with with `props` importing.

I'm using `next.js` (which is based on React) and I'm need to insert `props` from API endpoint right to my page.

[According to the example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/data-fetch/pages/index.js), it should looks like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({query}) {
    const res = await fetch(encodeURI(`url_here+${query}`));
    const json = await res.json();
```

The problem is with «what happens» next:

If I export my props (result of the function above) to page like this:

```
    return { props: {
       _id: json._id,
       ilvl: json.ilvl,
       ...
       checksum: json.checksum,
```

And import it like with using of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as an argument function:

```
function CharacterPage({ _id, id, ... }) {
    ...
}
```

> **THE PROBLEM**

That there are almost 16+ `key:values` in response json object from API endpoint.
So if I will follow to the codestyle from above that will be.. em.. guess you already understand.

So I could export result from API endpoint like:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({query}) {
    const res = await fetch(encodeURI(`url_here`));
    const json = await res.json();
    return {props: {json}
}
```

And import it, as one argument to the page like:

```
function CharacterPage({json})
```

But if I'll use `json.name` object keys on page (for conditional rendering) my IDE (WebStrom) shows me **unresolved variable** warning.

So where can I read about correct import practice and find react-import props example with lots of keys from JSON?

Should I use:
`let {id, name, ...etc} = json`
right after:
`function CharacterPage({json})`
for every key that I want to access or there is a better way/code practice for importing props?

Comment: your getServerSideProps is missing ending curly bracket. did you miss to copy it or error?

Comment: no, no, no it's not about `ServerSideProps` or anyother method, it's about code practice. I don't want to receive warning from IDE every time when I'm trying to access key. So don't think about correct syntax and so on. The point here, that you understand the logic.

Comment: Okay :) I just commented because I saw it. I added my idea in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My First idea is you can modify the JSON object in return of getServerSideProps. It would be more clear to identify which kind of object with attributes used here.

```
return {  props: {
   name: json.name,
   id: json.id
   ...
   }
}
```

If you cannot do that, it would be better to destructure initially.

```
let {id, name, ...etc} = json
```

But only destructure the elements you need. There is no need for destructuring all the elements.

Comment: The problem is that I needed in every key from `json` response from API. Sometime the response have `name` key, and sometimes it doesn't. So I use every key from JSON on page.

Comment: Okay... Then better to go for the bottom part. Your code will be easier to understand.

Comment: whats the difference between this and using a lifecycle method to do a fetch eg using componentwillmount and setting state and rendering state to view?

Comment: This question is not related to data fetching. This is about the way of reading the returning object.

componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in version 17. 

Using a separate method to define the data structure from fetch data is okay. It is not required to do all the tasks in one method. Mainly inside a life cycle method.